# Oculus Platform Initialize

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, gear-vr

When I try to initialize the platform:

`Oculus.Platform.Core.Initialize();`

I get an error:

> UnityException: Oculus Platform failed to initialize.

What could be the reason?

Device: GearVR and S8+;
Env: Unity v2017.1.1f1, Oculus Utilities v1.19.0, OVRPlugin v1.19.0, SDK v1.1.9.0.

Comment: Are you getting that error in editor or on the device? And did you insert your App ID?

Comment: On device. Identifier specified. If id is't specified, the SDK will generate an error.

Comment: I am guessing now. You did set OculusPlatformSettings form Menu Oculus Platform>Edit Settings and correct bundle identifier? Did you add oculus account to test accounts?

Comment: @filipst yes, i'm add test account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was with Oculus Runtime.

To find the problem need to use OculusLogGatherer. This util can gather all logs and perform auto analysis. If u see in auto analysis something like this:

> [Service_2017-11-15_14.59.51.txt] 15/11 14:59:54.088 {!ERROR!} [OAF
>   ERROR] ......\package\PackageManager.cpp(187) : Package does not
>   exist: oculus-runtime (1971015) [Service_2017-11-15_14.59.51.txt]
>   15/11 14:59:54.103 {!ERROR!} [OAF ERROR]
>   ......\package\PackageManager.cpp(187) : Package does not exist:
>   oculus-runtime (1971015) [Service_2017-11-15_14.59.51.txt] 15/11
>   15:00:09.078 {!ERROR!} [MobileConfigWrapper] Could not find
>   mobileconfig metadata at C:\Program
>   Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime\mobileconfig\MobileConfigMetadata.json

This means that you need to install\reinstall a Oculus Runtime.